# Regular Expression sql like _ wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex, sql-like

I am trying to set a regular expression which will work as sql like operator. I have replaced '%' wildcard by (.*) according to its position but i could fix % and _ both in one expression.

```
 var str = "English";
 var pp = "__g%";
```

I have replaced % like this

```
new RegExp(pp .replace("%", ".*")
```

but for number of '_' i have tried something like this

```
var match = new RegExp(likeExpr.replace("%", ".*").replace("_", "\w{2}")).exec(str) != null;
```

but got the wrong answer!! I am unable to find out what could be the exec match for _. the pattern contain two _ which means the sting having two character before g will true.

Comment: `.replace("_", "\\w")`

Comment: its results false for above scenario which should be true @AvinashRaj

Comment: Could you please specify the characters that `_` should match? As per docs, I see it can match &any* character. Do you want to match just English letters and digits? Do you also want it to match spaces? Any more restrictions?

Comment: it will exactly do the  same think as it do in sql like operator do.  but i am trying match only character no restriction on latter,digit or underscore @stribizhev